# libmesh: Parallel Mesh not enabled

Tags: mesh

I am trying to install `libmesh` for parallel computing (solid mechanics problems).
During installation, I can see the configure summary which states that I have almost all dependencies installed on the computer, however some important features e.g. `infinite elements` and `node constraints` are not enabled.

Following is the summary log of the `configure` command:

```
  ----------------------------------- SUMMARY -----------------------------------

  Package version.................... : libmesh-0.9.1pre

  C++ compiler type.................. : gcc4.6
  C++ compiler....................... : mpicxx
  C compiler......................... : mpicc
  Fortran compiler................... : mpif90
  Build Methods...................... : dbg devel opt

  CPPFLAGS...(dbg)................... : -DDEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC
  CXXFLAGS...(dbg)................... : -O0 -felide-constructors -g -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wunused -Wpointer-arith -Wformat -Wparentheses -std=c++0x -Woverloaded-virtual -fopenmp
  CFLAGS.....(dbg)................... : -g -Wimplicit -fopenmp

  CPPFLAGS...(devel)................. :
  CXXFLAGS...(devel)................. : -O2 -felide-constructors -g -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wunused -Wpointer-arith -Wformat -Wparentheses -Wuninitialized -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -std=c++0x -Woverloaded-virtual -Wdisabled-optimization -fopenmp
  CFLAGS.....(devel)................. : -O2 -g -Wimplicit -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -fopenmp

  CPPFLAGS...(opt)................... : -DNDEBUG
  CXXFLAGS...(opt)................... : -O2 -felide-constructors -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -std=c++0x -Wdisabled-optimization -fopenmp
  CFLAGS.....(opt)................... : -O2 -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -fopenmp

  Install dir........................ : /usr/local
  Build user......................... : mubeen
  Build host......................... : Khwarizmi
  Build architecture................. : x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Git revision....................... : 8fbff282323e513a967bd53345316c26c6a54107

  Library Features:
    adaptive mesh refinement......... : yes
    complex variables................ : no
    example suite.................... : yes
    ghosted vectors.................. : yes
    high-order shape functions....... : yes
    id size (boundaries)............. : 2 bytes
    id size (dofs)................... : 4 bytes
    id size (processors)............. : 2 bytes
    id size (subdomains)............. : 2 bytes
    infinite elements................ : no
    Dirichlet constraints............ : yes
    node constraints................. : no
    parallel mesh.................... : yes
    performance logging.............. : no
    periodic boundary conditions..... : yes
    reference counting............... : yes
    shape function 2nd derivatives... : yes
    stack trace files................ : no
    variational smoother............. : yes
    xdr binary I/O................... : yes

  Optional Packages:
    boost............................ : yes
    cppunit.......................... : yes
    eigen............................ : yes
    exodus........................... : yes
       version....................... : v5.22
    fparser.......................... : yes
       build from version............ : release
    glpk............................. : yes
    gmv.............................. : yes
    gzstream......................... : yes
    hdf5............................. : yes
    laspack.......................... : yes
    libhilbert....................... : yes
    metis............................ : yes
    mpi.............................. : yes
    nanoflann........................ : yes
    nemesis.......................... : yes
       version....................... : v5.22
    netcdf........................... : yes
       version....................... : 4
    openmp........................... : yes
    parmetis......................... : yes
    petsc............................ : yes
       version....................... : 3.3.0
    sfcurves......................... : yes
    slepc............................ : yes
    tbb.............................. : yes
    c++ threads...................... : yes
       flavor........................ : tbb::tbb_thread
    tecio............................ : no
    tecplot...(vendor binaries)...... : yes
    tetgen........................... : yes
    triangle......................... : yes
    trilinos......................... : yes
       AztecOO....................... : yes
       NOX........................... : yes
       ML............................ : no
       Tpetra........................ : yes
       DTK........................... : no
    vtk.............................. : yes
       version....................... : 5.8.0
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have also used the `--enable-nodeconstraint=yes` option, but there is no change in the summary of `configure`.
I will be very thankful for any helpful comment bout this problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Quick answer

Always check `configure --help`. For libmesh it has the following lines:

```
    --enable-nodeconstraint build with node constraints suppport
    --enable-ifem           build with infinite elements
```

### More details

Also it is handy to save `configure` output into a file:

```
    configure --enable-ifem --enable-nodeconstraint 2>&1 | tee configure.out
```

Then check if the `configure.out` contains the correct options:

```
  infinite elements................ : yes
  Dirichlet constraints............ : yes
  node constraints................. : yes
```

### Troubleshooting

If it does not for some unexpected reason you could search the `config.log` file that is always created by `configure` for the specific tests that failed.

A good first approach would be to run

```
grep -B1 "compilation terminated" config.log
```

The quite long output would look like:

```
....
<many lines omitted>
....
--
conftest.cpp:140:36: fatal error: /usr/include/Eigen/Eigen: No such file or dir..
compilation terminated.
--
conftest.cpp:107:36: fatal error: /usr/include/Eigen/Eigen: No such file or dir..
compilation terminated.
--
conftest.cpp:143:31: fatal error: /usr/include/glpk.h: No such file or dir...
compilation terminated.
--
conftest.cpp:110:31: fatal error: /usr/include/glpk.h: No such file or dir...
compilation terminated.
```

Which is clearly indicative of why certain features were not available.